# How to transpose and autofill a dataframe with python?

Tags: python, pandas, melt

I have a dataframe like below:

```
NaN    1/1/2018    2/1/2018
item1    1    2
item2    3    4
```

I would like to transform the dataframe to make it look like this:

```
Date    Item    Price
1/1/2018    item1    1
1/1/2018    item2    3
2/1/2018    item1    2
2/1/2018    item2    4
```

I have tried df.pivot and df.t but neither works. Any suggestions or hints are very much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: `df.stack().reset_index()`, assuming that `item1, item2` is currently the index

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`pd.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) like so:

```
pd.melt(DF, id_vars=['NaN'], var_name='Date', value_name='Price')

     NaN      Date  Price
0  item1  1/1/2018      1
1  item2  1/1/2018      3
2  item1  2/1/2018      2
3  item2  2/1/2018      4
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I tried your method but I got an error as NaN is actually a blank cell. I am very new to pandas so I guess I will need to name those columns first?

Comment: I assume it's because your first column is the index? You can try `df.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)` and then `id_vars=['index']` and that should work.

Comment: I have followed your code and I got 'TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable'. I guess I can get the logic of solving the task but there may exist other format issue(maybe?) to be taken care of first? Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with pd.melt() like so:

```
pd.melt(df, id_vars = ['NaN'])
```

This results in:

[image]

Comment: Could you share the way to name those columns? I am new to pandas and I tried df2.columns=['Date','Item','Price'] but I got NaN in the column rather than in the header. Thanks!